# PHP arithmetic operation (addition)

Tags: php

`floor( 500 * (1.4 / 100) )` gives me 6
and
`floor( 500 * 1.4 / 100 )` gives me 7

Can anyone help me understand how PHP arithmetic works internally.

Comment: How can the second example give you 7 ? That doesn't seem possible to me.

Comment: You meant `floor( 500 * 1.4 / 100)` ?

Comment: I find it unlikely that 500 * 1.4 * 100 returns anything close to 7.

Comment: Is it a typo in the second example (the last `*`)? It meant to be ` floor( 500 * 1.4 / 100 )`, right?

Comment: The second expression returns 70000.

Comment: but how can it round down to 6... when the result itself is 7?

Answer (score 6):

It works like in any other language. Try for example javascript:

```
    (500*(1.4 / 100)) // this will give you 6.999999999999999
    (500* 1.4 / 100)  // this will give you 7
```

The problem is, that PHP has internal setting which tells him about precission with which he displays float numbers. Try doing something like that:

```
    php > ini_set('precision', 17);
    php > echo ( 500 * (1.4 / 100) );
    6.9999999999999991
    php > echo ( 500 * 1.4 / 100 );
    7
    php >
```

I assume you've tried the code above without ini_set (using default settings – probably 14 as precision), and it returned you 7 in both results:

```
    php > echo ( 500 * 1.4 / 100 );
    7
    php > echo ( 500 * (1.4 / 100) );
    7
    php >
```